# Multipart to Singlepart in ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, multipart, singlepart

How can I convert a `Multi Polygon` GPKG to single `Polygon`s using `ogr2ogr`? (I'm working in a Jupyter Hub environment without access to QGIS.)

Answer (score 5):

`ogr2ogr` has an [`-explodecollections`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-explodecollections) flag. Different name – same result.

`ogr2ogr -explodecollections singlepart.gpkg multipart.gpkg`

Comment: That is even documented https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html "Produce one feature for each geometry in any kind of geometry collection in the source file, applied after any -sql option."

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, adding it to the answer.